# What is the “power” in the kingdom of God?

Tags: jesus, mark, kingdom-of-god

In Mark 9:1 Jesus says:

> Truly I say to you, there are some of those who are standing here who will not taste death until they see the kingdom of God after it has come *with power.* (NASB, emphasis mine).

What is the “power” that Jesus is referring to? Can one assume that the Kingdom of God was, to some extent, already present on earth but that there would be an added power after Jesus’s resurrection that wasn’t there before?

Comment: Wonder if the “taste death” part of the passage is crucial to its right interpretation. If so, Rev 6:9,10 is a parallel passage.

Answer (score 3):

"Power". In Acts 2:2 the power is represented by "a sound from heaven as of a rushing mighty wind".

This power further showed itself as something visible v3, "there appeared to them divided tongues, as of fire".

This power broke across usual speech patterns v3, "they were all filled with the Holy Spirit and began to speak with other tongues".

Here the Kingdom of God cuts across other kingdoms as Parthians, Medes, Elamites, people from Mesoptamia, Judea and all the other places verses 9-11 mention, "hear...the wonderful works of God".

These events herald the coming of the Holy Spirit to indwell and infill. Galatians 5:22-23 and Ephesians 5:18-21 show His work in the church.

Previously in the Old Testament: Exodus 31:3 Bezalel was filled with wisdom of the Holy Spirit, not the Holy Spirit.

Isaiah 59:21 The Spirit was upon the prophet, but in 1 Corinthians 6:19 "your body is the temple of the Holy Spirit who is in you".

Answer (score 0):

> NKJV Luke 17:20 Now when He was asked by the Pharisees when the kingdom of God would come, He answered them and said, “The kingdom of God does not come with observation; 21 nor will they say, ‘See here!’ or ‘See there!’ For indeed, the kingdom of God is within you.”

The kingdom of God exists in the spiritual realm.

> John 3:3 Jesus answered and said to him, “Most assuredly, I say to you, unless one is born again, he cannot see the kingdom of God.”

One can see the kingdom of God as soon as he is born again.

Berean Study Bible Mark 9:1

> Then Jesus said to them, “Truly I tell you, there are some standing here who will not taste death before they see the kingdom of God **arrive with power**.”

arrive
ἐληλυθυῖαν (elēlythuian)
Verb - **Perfect** Participle Active - Accusative Feminine Singular
Strong's Greek 2064: To come, go.

One day in the future, the kingdom of God will be completed or perfected with power.

Answer (score -1):

W**hat is the “power” in the kingdom of God?**

Jesu promises some of his apostles,that they would not taste death until they see the kingdom.

In Mark 9:1 Jesus says:

> Truly I say to you, there are some of those who are standing here who
> will not taste death until they see the kingdom of God after it has
> come with power. (NASB).

This promise was fulfilled "six days later" (or “eight” according to Luke, who apparently includes the day of the promise and that of the fulfillment) when Peter, James, and John accompanied Jesus on a "  high mountain"

The Transfiguration

Mark 9:2 (NASB)

> 2 Six days later, Jesus *took with Him Peter and [a]James and John,
> and *brought them up on a high mountain by themselves. And He was
> transfigured before them;

Luke 9:28-36  (NASB)

The Transfiguration

> 28 Some eight days after these sayings, He took along Peter and John
> and James, and went up on the mountain to pray. 29 And while He was
> praying, the appearance of His face became different, and His clothing
> became white and gleaming. 30 And behold, two men were talking with
> Him; and they were Moses and Elijah, 31 who, appearing in glory, were
> speaking of His departure which He was about to accomplish at
> Jerusalem. 32 Now Peter and his companions had been overcome with
> sleep; but when they were fully awake, they saw His glory and the two
> men standing with Him.
>
> 33 And as these were leaving Him, Peter said to Jesus, “Master, it is
> good for us to be here; let us make three [d]tabernacles: one for You,
> and one for Moses, and one for Elijah”—not realizing what he was
> saying. 34 While he was saying this, a cloud formed and began to
> overshadow them; and they were afraid as they entered the cloud. 35
> Then a voice came out of the cloud, saying, “This is My Son, My Chosen
> One; listen to Him!” 36 And when the voice had spoken, Jesus was found
> alone. And they kept silent, and reported to no one in those days any
> of the things which they had seen.

Comment: (-1) The answer you're giving here fails to mention power or show the coming of a kingdom in any obvious way, and so doesn't really justify its conclusion. What makes this more than an assumption? Maybe finding an early Christian source which agrees with this conclusion would be helpful, if there's nothing linguistic to go on.